# Running python file using batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a "smaller" problem in batch file. I'm calling a Python "miniprogram" from batch file like this
mybat.bat:

`FOR %%f IN (*.oldextension) DO (C:\Python27\python.exe myPython.py -i "%%f" -o "%%f.newextension")`

It is working good, but I want to rename/change the -o(output) filename to a new extension only and remove the old extension.
So let's say
**file.oldextension --> file.newextension**, because now it looks like **file.oldextension --> file.oldextension.newextension**

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR %%f IN (*.oldextension) DO (
    C:\Python27\python.exe myPython.py -i "%%f" -o "%%~nf.newextension"
)
```

Where `%%~nf` is the name of the file referenced by `%%f`

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I'll accept it as a good answer in ~3 minutes. You saved me some hours :)